# DiscordJS, Gulp reload bot on file save?

Tags: gulp, discord

I just started messing around with Discordjs and I'm working on just a super simple bot example, but the most annoying thing is whenever I make any changes I need to stop the bot in command line and execute the command to come back online in order for any of my code changes to take affect. Is there any way to automate this process? lets say I make a change to bot.js, would there be a way for something like gulp to detect this and restart the bot?

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like nodemon (http://nodemon.io/).

Install it by running: `npm install -g nodemon`. This will install it globally on your computer. Then just run `nodemon` on the console instead of `node myfilehere.js`.

Make sure the file you are running with `node myfilehere.js` is the same name on package.json under "main"

Comment: I'd definitely agree. nodemon is bomb.

Comment: awwe he beat me to it. Yes this is what I use for my discordjs bot